# Hyper-V and Virtualisation memory management

Tags: memory-management, virtual-machine, hyper-v

Hypervisors and Memory Management

I have been using virtual machines for years and never really had any issues. I have primarily used VMWare's free single ESXi host and had nothing but success. Because I have never had any issues I have never delved in much deeper. I have however always been very wary of loading the system up and get a lot of spare resources handy.

I have recently purchased a new server and we have decided to give Hyper-V a try and see how that goes. We have a fairly small team but utilise lots of servers for testing etc.

My question relates to memory and how much I need to leave free or available for the host machine to run appropriately.

Setup:Dell Server 24 Cores: 48GB Ram

When I run taskmgr in the windows host instance I see the following:

Physical Memory: 49139
Cached: 14933
Available: 17743
Free: 2982

What exactly do these figures mean? What is the difference between free and available?

My server uses hardly any CPU resources ever and has 10 Production servers running on it without a single user complaint ever about speed of the services.

Am I able to run up another server with 2GB ram effectivly leaving 982MB free? or am I starting to push my requirements a little?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn’t use the host partition for anything other than Hyper-V (although you can run security and infrastructure software such as management agents, backup agents and firewalls). Therefore, that 2GB recommendation assumes you aren’t going to run any extra applications or server roles in the parent partition.

Hyper-V doesn’t let you allocate memory directly to the host partition. It essentially uses whatever memory is left over. Therefore, you have to remember to leave 2GB of your host server’s memory not allocated so it’s available for the parent partition.

[Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh750394.aspx)

Comment: So when you talk about the host partition, can this be split across a single raid array but just be a different "Partition"?